# C# - updating variable from async method callback BY REF - WebClient class

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, webclient

I would like to update a variable by ref inside the WebClient async callback.

it seems that the 2nd parameter in `.DownloadStringAsync()` (token) does not accept by ref, and is `readonly` (e.UserState) so im out of ideas.

How can that be done ?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string a = "AAA";
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.DownloadStringCompleted += Wc_DownloadStringCompleted;
            wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://someurl.to.json"), a);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }

    private static void Wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // do something with e.result ...;
        // update the caller method's 'a' variable (by ref not possible as token) with "BBB"
    }
```

Comment: Try moving your variable into the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netframework-4.8), you should be using `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` instead of `System.Net.WebClient` (unless you are at very old versions of .NET).

Using `HttpClient`, this task is very simple:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string a;
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            a = client.GetStringAsync("http://someurl.to.json").Result;
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [DownloadStringTaskAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadstringtaskasync?view=netframework-4.8) rather than [DownloadStringAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadstringasync?view=netframework-4.8).

```cs
async static Task Main(string[] args)
{
    string a = "AAA";
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += Wc_DownloadStringCompleted;
        a = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri("http://someurl.to.json"));
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
    Console.WriteLine(a);
}

private static void Wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // do something with e.result ...;
    // update the caller method's 'a' variable (by ref not possible as token) with "BBB"
}
```

If you really want to use `DownloadStringAsync`, you may need to make your variable as a global variable.

Or Even much better, Use HttpClient instead. The WebClient and HttpWebRequest things are old now.